# Quantum Field Theory, questions about fields and their vacuum state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum, gravitational-waves, quantum-states

Are the fields in their empty state a single indivisible and static entity? I would also like to know if the gravitational field also has a vacuum state and if the other fields are permanently linked to it.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, but in quantum theory the word 'static' here means that there is no evolution over time (except a global phase), it does not mean that a sequence of observations will all yield the same result
2. yes; 'indivisible' in the sense that it is continuous and you can't separate one part from another so as to leave a hole where there is no quantum field
3. yes, but it depends on how gravity is to be modeled and this is an open research problem
4. yes, anything with energy or pressure or stress interacts with the gravitational field, so that means everything interacts with the gravitational field

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers